# Store URL redirection not working on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10

I'm trying to determine which Store URL I'm supposed to use. Now that `Windows 10` is released I want to make sure that the Store URL is correct and that the redirection works as intended.

I followed Microsoft's own documentation ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228343.aspx)). Basically they say that I can use the following url-protocol/scheme to open the store for both Windows 10 and Windows 8: `ms-windows-store://pdp/?PFN=Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe`. But this only seem to work on Windows 10, on Windows 8.1 it will open the store but not show the app. They recommend that one use this: `ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9WZDNCRFHVJL` but say that it is only recommended for `Windows 10` users (also it doesn't work if tried on `Windows 8.1`).

I think I've tried all combinations on that page but it won't work for both OS:es. This can't possible be intended?

Comment: Might it be that the actual app ID that you're linking to is a Windows 10 app? That would explain why the store opens but you don't get anywhere. Have you tried with a "pure" Windows 8 app link? What happened then?

Comment: It's my own app, and if anything it's an Windows 8.1 app. :) I tried a pure Windows 8.1 link also, it oddly they didn't work either. I got redirected to a microsoft webpage. :/

Comment: Oh, oki. Then I don't have any more suggestions right now. I hope someone with more knowledge will come and help you soon :)

Comment: I have a Windows 8.1 store app, and I use the following: `ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=mypackagename`. (The difference is that there is no `/` in the url). It works when the app is run under either Win 8.1 or Win 10.

Comment: Thank you @chue, I will try this tomorrow.